# How to create and retrieve using the Java API an Elasticsearch field with a complex type?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following:

```
final duration = (jsonBuilder()
        .startObject()
        .field('start', new DateTime(testResult.startTime, dateTimeZone))
        .field('end', new DateTime(testResult.endTime, dateTimeZone))
        .endObject())

client.prepareIndex('builds', 'test')
        .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                .startObject()
                .field("duration", duration)
                .endObject())

SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch('builds')
        .setQuery(boolQuery()
                .must(termQuery('_type', 'test')))
        .execute()
        .actionGet()

final source = searchResponse.hits.hits[0].source as Map<String, Object>
```

How do I retrieve the values of `duration.start` and `duration.end` from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `field()` doesn't recognize `XContentBuilder` as a value despite what http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index_.html implies. From the source code for `XContentBuilder`, it's unclear to me how to use `field` with `XContentBuilder`.

It's easy enough to use a Map as a value, though.

```
final duration = [
        'start': new DateTime(testResult.startTime, dateTimeZone),
        'end': new DateTime(testResult.endTime, dateTimeZone)]

client.prepareIndex('builds', 'test')
        .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                .startObject()
                .field("duration", duration)
                .endObject())

SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch('builds')
        .setQuery(boolQuery()
                .must(termQuery('_type', 'test')))
        .execute()
        .actionGet()

final source = searchResponse.hits.hits[0].source

assertThat(source.duration.start, equalTo('1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z'))
assertThat(source.duration.end, equalTo('1970-01-01T00:00:00.002Z'))
```

Answer (score 5):

Try 1..!

```
    SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
    Map<String, Object> s=searchHits[0].sourceAsMap();
    Map<String, Date> duration=(Map<String, Date>) s.get("duration");
    Date start=duration.get("start");
    Date end=duration.get("end");
```

Try 2..!

```
    SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int length = searchHits.length;
    builder.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i == length - 1) {
            builder.append(searchHits[i].getSourceAsString());
        } else {
            builder.append(searchHits[i].getSourceAsString());
            builder.append(",");
        }
    }
    builder.append("]");
         String result= builder.toString();
```

it will return a string and its a valid JSON array use JSON parser and fetch values as normal json process..!